# Create Website using Github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I am creating a website on github, but after doing everything when I am trying to open the link its throwing me an error 404.

Need your help on this.
link : https://github.com/manasgrg/portfolio/

Comment: Please provide more details. What you expected and what actually happens? At SO, we help each other with coding issues, not with just service-usage..

Answer (score 1):

When you want to create a webpage with GitHub for a repository, you have to upload your website's files on a branch called "gh-pages". It looks like you did it.

If your repository is located in https://github.com/manasgrg/portfolio, search for your webpage over there: https://manasgrg.github.io/portfolio

Seems to me like everything's working.

Answer (score 0):

Manas Garg. there are 2 types of Github pages, you make a question like you not using GitHub properly.

a) Your personal GitHub page looked like `*username*.github.io` (this is the best place for your CV)

b) Your repo GitHub page (your case at the question) and @Charles Müller is right. and your link should look like `*username*.github.io/*reponame*`

In both case GitHub pages will be looking for your index.html, in your repo, you should have index.html.

for further study checkout at:

for case a)
 https://pages.github.com/

for case b) 
https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/github-for-windows-users-16749?l=8MGXzodxC_5206218965